# DDD Dependency Example

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm thinking about implementing DDD. Here the example:

I have 2 domain entities: `Identity` and `Pool`

```
public class Identity
{
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public bool Active { get; private set;}
  public Guid PoolId { get; private set;}
  ....

  public static Identity Create(){...}

  public void Enable(){...}
  public void Disable(){...}
  public void UpdatePassword(){...}
  ...
}

public class Pool
{
  public Guid Id { get; private set; }
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public bool Active { get; private set;}
  ....

  public static Pool Create(){...}

  public void Enable(){...}
  public void Disable(){...}
  public void Archive(){...}
  ...
}
```

The issue is "I want to add validation/checking if the pool is already archived or disabled, `identity.Enable()`, `identity.Disable()`, `identity.UpdatePassword()` can't be executed (maybe throws exception that pool already archived)".

My questions are:

1. Which layer should handle this logic? Domain Logic or Application logic?
2. How should I implement this?

Could anyone help me explain more about that?

Note: They are not in different machine (or microservice), they are using same database.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155255/54734

Comment: I think no, because It is talking about side effects using event pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a BC is dependent on data from another one you are probably going to have an eventual consistency scenario.

You can either store the `Pool` as a value object in the dependent BC and update its data based on, say, events received from the upstream BC or you can store the `Pool` data as a VO on the dependent objects themselves.  That is going to be a judgment call on your end.  Since you would have the relevant data locally you could check it locally.  However, it doesn't guarantee that the data is not stale.  You would, once the data is altered to be consistent ensure that you compensate for any incorrect changes.

Your domain logic is required to enforce invariants.  I like to pass in any data to the domain that may be required to enforce those invariants.  In your case the integration/application concern would retrieve the current pool status and pass that into the domain method as a parameter.  This allows for easy testing.  You may decide to move that responsibility out of the domain much in the way one does with authorisation but, again, that is your call and YMMV.

Even so you would need to compensate for any commands executed that were not supposed to be executed.  The same applies to ordering goods online.  You may have added a product to your shopping cart but on checkout the item is no longer available.